# Running different quality profiles on different source directories

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube5.1

Say I have the following sources defined in my sonar project properties file.

```
sonar.sources=src/client/app,src/server
```

Could I get SonarQube to use one quality profile for one path, and a different profile for the other?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to apply multiple quality profiles to a project only as separate SonarQube projects with separate keys and analyses.

I.e. You'd have to analyze twice: once for each directory.

Your next question, of course, is how to re-combine the products of the two separate analyses. The answer is that that's only available with the Governance($) plugin, and Governance is only LTS-compatible (5.6 at this writing.)

Comment: OK thanks, we actually are running 5.6, so will take a look at the Governance plugin!